# How can I go through all folder and rename files

Tags: batch, batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder that contains a lot of numeric folders (1,2,3...). Inside them are some pictures.

How can I go through each folder and rename pictures to 1,2,3...

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/) and its Ctrl+M multiple rename function. You may need to go through every folder, but setting once the pattern of the filename should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If your in Windows, this previous post may be of help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304025/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-powershell-with-sequential-numeric-suffixes

It utilizes Windows Powershell's Rename-Item cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

Over the years I've tried a number of file renaming utilities. I ended up choosing Bulk Renamer Utility http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php as my favorite, and I've yet to find one I like better.

It is very flexible and powerful, so takes some time to learn all it's features, but once you get the hang of it (for the kinds of things you do most often), you may be able to do just about any kind of renaming task you could think of.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has been recommended multiple times (and I have found it useful for similar tasks), you may wish to try [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) which is available [here](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php). Per the product page:

> Bulk Rename Utility allows you to easily rename files and entire folders based upon extremely flexible criteria.

It is available for Windows and is free for non-commercial use. It comes with no adware. Installation is simple - just download and extract to your preferred folder.

Once "installed", double-click `Bulk Rename Utility.exe` to bring up the main program window.

While the interface is somewhat complex, there is a manual provided with the download. For your case, assuming you didn't mind going folder by folder, you could simple select the files you wished to rename and (if I am understanding what you want) use the "Append Folder Name" feature to place a corresponding suffix for the folder e.g.

[image: Bulk Rename Utility Append Folder Name Function Example]

Here is a slightly more advanced example of how you could replace the entire name of a file with the folder name and number each file sequentially at the same time by combining functions:

[image: Bulk Rename Utility Complex File Rename Based On Folder And Sequence]

## Caveats

- Before tinkering, I would back up any important files.
- The effects of your rename might not be immediately apparent when you adjust options. If you see no change in the selected file name(s) after you modify something, leave the settings alone and simply deselect/re-select the items. Assuming your settings are valid, you should see the (green modified) filename change.
- Don't forget to press the big "Rename" button to actually apply changes once you're happy with the naming sequence.